# Create a new version of application to publish using poetry

Tags: python-poetry

I was trying to find answer on sites but could not get it.

Actually i have an application in python for which maintaining versions using poetry.

Right now when i run below command it shows the current version of app :

```
poetry version
ami-utility 0.1.1-alpha.0
```

i had already published this version to repo and have made many changes in app after that release. but now when i am running poetry build .. it is again creating the same version :

```
poetry build
Building ami-utility (0.1.1-alpha.0)
   - Building sdist
   - Built ami-utility-0.1.1-a0.tar.gz
   - Building wheel
   - Built ami-utility-0.1.1-a0-py3-none-any-whl
```

but now i want to create a new version .
Could you please suggest how to create now a new version and publish the new version?

Thanks
Sharad

Comment: did you run `poetry version patch` to update the version's patch level already? Or rather, which version do you want to release, `0.1.2`, or `0.2.0` or `1.0.0`?

Comment: You can change the version string in `pyproject.toml` directly as well. -- Doc for CLI: https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#version -- Doc for `pyproject.toml`: https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#version -- Standard for the format of version strings: https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it worked with below command

```
poetry version 0.1.2
```

and then publish again.